# Ubuntu cannot read Thunderboltex 4 devices

Tags: thunderbolt, pci

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.04 
**Mainboard:** ASUS TUF GAMING B760M-PLUS
**PCI board:** ASUS Thunderboltex 4

I have configured my computer with the specs above. The mainboard doesn't have a Thunderbolt port so I installed Thunderbolt PCI board. But Ubuntu can't recognize the Thunderbolt device connected to the board. The connected device is the raid controller.

I've already installed bolt, and Thunderbolt tools using `apt`, and changed BIOS settings about security levels.

How can I fix it?

[image: dmsg-of-thunderbolt]

[image: boltctl]

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

I think last part is the key to solve this problem.

Commands don't work. I entered a command with sudo, but it says permission denied.

```
log : journalctl -b 0
```

```
 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: pci 0000:02:03.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: [8086:1137] type 00 class 0x0c0340


-------


 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: ACPI: bus type thunderbolt registered

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: thunderbolt 0000:03:00.0: error -EINVAL: cannot obtain PCI resources, aborting

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: fbcon: Taking over console

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: i2c i2c-0: 1/4 memory slots populated (from DMI)

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: i2c i2c-0: Memory type 0x22 not supported yet, not instantiating SPD

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: thunderbolt: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -22

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: usb: port power management may be unreliable

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: init 0000:05:00.0 fail, -16

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -16

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: xHCI Host Controller

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: idma64 idma64.0: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit

 Jan 11 12:15:08 m2mcx-System-Product-Name kernel: asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded

---------------


 Jan 11 12:15:57 m2mcx-System-Product-Name fwupd[4010]: 03:15:57:0444 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1

 Jan 11 12:15:57 m2mcx-System-Product-Name fwupd[4010]: 03:15:57:0445 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1

 Jan 11 12:15:57 m2mcx-System-Product-Name fwupd[4010]: 03:15:57:0483 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI Device Firmware: No releases found: no HWIDs matched 6c9ad27c-7dac-5b6c-8414-e6c2f0f67080|49444c26-88e4-56de-ae27-ec8b939baeed

 Jan 11 12:15:57 m2mcx-System-Product-Name fwupd[4010]: 03:15:57:0485 FuEngine             failed to get releases for Intel Management Engine: No releases found: no HWIDs matched 6c9ad27c-7dac-5b6c-8414-e6c2f0f67080|49444c26-88e4-56de-ae27-ec8b939baeed

 Jan 11 12:15:58 m2mcx-System-Product-Name fwupd[4010]: 03:15:58:0592 FuEngine             failed to add device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.5/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/mtd/mtd0ro: attribute size returned no data


------


 Jan 11 12:15:58 m2mcx-System-Product-Name fwupd[4010]: 03:15:58:0592 FuEngine             failed to add device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.5/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/mtd/mtd0ro: attribute size returned no data

 Jan 11 14:21:23 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[17509]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tee -a /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/authorized

 Jan 11 14:21:23 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[17508]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/echo 1

 Jan 11 14:21:59 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[17818]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ls

 Jan 11 14:25:33 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[19645]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw -c display

 Jan 11 14:25:45 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[19751]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw -c thunderbolt

 Jan 11 14:25:50 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[19800]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw -c

 Jan 11 14:25:55 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[19850]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw -c pci

 Jan 11 14:25:59 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[19890]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw

 Jan 11 14:26:06 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[19948]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw -c maple

 Jan 11 14:27:46 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[20802]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw

 Jan 11 14:27:55 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[20882]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw

 Jan 11 14:29:45 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[21813]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw -c pci

 Jan 11 14:29:49 m2mcx-System-Product-Name sudo[21853]:      ick : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw -c pci0
```